# In PCA, why do we assume that the covariance matrix is always diagonalizable?

Tags: pca, eigenvalues

In Principal Component Analysis, what is the justification for the assumption that the covariance matrix is always a diagonalizable matrix?

What happens when the covariance matrix is not diagonalizable, i.e. its eigenvectors do not span the complete vector space?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Covariance matrix is a symmetric matrix, hence it is always diagonalizable.

In fact, in the diagonalization, $C=PDP^{-1}$, we know that we can choose $P$ to be an orthogonal matrix.

It belongs to a larger class of matrix known as Hermitian matrix that guarantees that they can be diagonalized.

Comment: what if there are repeated eigenvalues? how do you ensure the orthogonality then?

Comment: It doesn't require the eigenvalues to be distinct. One possible way to prove it is via [Schur's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/823282/306553). I was introduced to the theorem via mathematical induction many years ago.